# How to appropriately get the text and color of the text to toggle/change between 4 colors?

Tags: java, javafx, colors, toggle

I currently have my JavaFX code set up to toggle between the colors blue and red. When the program runs, a button with the text "Change to Red" appears in blue text. If I click the button it changes to "Change to Blue" written in red text. If I click it again the cycle starts over. What I'd like to do is apply the same pattern but use four colors. For instance, I'd like it to start with:

"Change to Red", written in blue text.

Then after the click.

"Change to Green", written in red text.

Then after the click.

"Change to Purple", written in green text.

Then after the click.

"Change to Blue", written in purple text.

Then after the click start the cycle over again with:

"Change to Red", written in blue text.

etc. etc.

This is the code I have for two colors:

```
public class FirstUserInput extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Change to Red");
        btn.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

    btn.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (btn.getTextFill() == Color.RED) {
            btn.setText("Change to Red");
            btn.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            btn.setText("Change to Blue");
            btn.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me change this code to work with four colors?

Comment: Why do you just not expand what you have to three if statements?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. The order and colors get all mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to reduce the code you have to write with if-else statements then could use arrays or enums to hold all the options and on each action event choose the correct one like :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application {

    private int index = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Change to Red");

        String allTexts[] = { "Change to Red", "Change to Blue", "Change to Green", "Change to Pink" };
        Color allColors[] = { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.PINK, Color.GREEN };

        btn.setOnAction(e -> {

            index++;
            if(index >= allTexts.length ) {
                index = 0;
            }

            btn.setText(allTexts[index]);
            btn.setTextFill(allColors[index]);

        });

        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(btn);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Well the above works when the changes are sequential I hope that what you are looking for.

Comment: It says cannot find variable index. I'm trying to remedy that right now. If you can help  please tell me how to remedy this.

Comment: @Eatel As i pointed out as a commend in the code you need to define the index variable as global like `private int index = 0 ;` Anyway I will update my answer giving a complete example.

Comment: It doesn't work right. The colors don't match the text. It changes to pink when it's supposed to change to blue and vice versa.

Comment: That's because I just add the colors i choose and not yours.. All you have to do is to modify the allColors array and put inside the color you want. The same logic is applied to allTexts about the Text you want to display with the sequence you want.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out shortly after. My bad I forgot to reply and went to sleep. Thanks I'll give you the green check mark.